# Imagemagick clipping out shapes and adding an expanded background

Tags: php, imagemagick

Using imagemagick, I'm looking to add an expanded background color to an image. My source looks like this:

[image: source image]

And this is the desired output (the background color will be white, but this is for clarity):
[image: source image]

Step 1 seems to be filling the background with my desired color, but I can't find a way to remove the background *outside* the shape. This will also be a problem if the source image contains any of the desired background color already (because it will be made transparent).

Ideas?

Comment: Not at a computer for next few days but try looking at `-morphology edgeout diamond` to outine your black shape.

Comment: You could also set `-fill red` and do `-draw "color 0,0 floodfill"` to fill just the outside with red, then `-fill` and `-/+opaque` to make everything not red and not black into green and that way you could fill the interiors.

Comment: You don't say if your initial shape is a vector or bitmap...

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfect but should do the job:

```
convert ( in.png -resize 200% -flatten -negate -morphology Dilate Disk:20 \
-fuzz 90% -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" -fill green \
-colorize 100% -resize 50% ) in.png -composite out.png
```